# OPTIONS as been blocker by CORS policy (trying to send cookie)

Tags: reactjs, go, cookies, axios, cors

i have some trouble to send my backend cookie to my frontend with axios. I understand that i need to use `withCredential : true` in my axios request, like so:

```
 const handleSubmit = (event) => {
event.preventDefault()
console.log(event)
// axios.defaults.withCredentials = true
const headers = { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', withCredentials: true}
const data = new FormData(event.currentTarget)
// console.log(data)

const [email, password] = [data.get('email'), data.get('password')]

axios.post('http://localhost:8080/login/', {
  email,
  password,
}, {withCredentials: true} , {headers}) 
.then((response) => {
  for(let entry of response.headers.entries()) {
    console.log('header', entry)
  }
}).then(function (response) {
  console.log(response)
  this.setCookie()
})
.catch(function (error) {
  console.log(error)
})}
```

but when i call this request, i have this error:

[image]

this is how i try to handle CORS in my backend:

```
func CORS(next http.HandlerFunc) http.HandlerFunc {
return func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
  w.Header().Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
  w.Header().Add("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true")
  w.Header().Add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "")
  w.Header().Add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "Content-Type")
  w.Header().Add("Content-Type", "text/plain")
  w.Header().Add("Origin", "")
  if r.Method == "OPTIONS" {
    fmt.Println("YES OPTIONS")
    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
  }

  next(w, r)
}}
```

if i remove the `withCredentials: true`, the request is working and i can see my cookie in the header of the response, but my cookie is not set in the application tab.

Can you help me? Thanks a lot!

Comment: You haven't implemented CORS properly. My piece of advice: do not even try to implement CORS "manually", as doing so simply is too error-prone. Instead, find a good CORS middleware and learn how to configure it (after [familiarising yourself with the CORS protocol itself](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS), of course). While waiting for [a better alternative](https://twitter.com/jub0bs/status/1585696295867465728), I would recommend something like https://github.com/rs/cors.

Comment: I've just released a CORS middleware library for Go, which I believe is superior to the others: https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/jub0bs/fcors